# Response bodies written as non-human readable in proxpy

Tags: python, http, encoding, io, proxy

I am writing a plugin for proxpy. This is basically an HTTP/HTTPS proxy written in python. You extend it by implementing two functions, the arguments to which is the HTTP request and response respectively. Something like this:

method1(request):

#your implementation

method2(response):

#your implementation

I want to simply write the requests and responses to a file.

The response object has a `serialize()` function which I call to get the entire response as a string and then I write it to a file. Here is my code:

```
def proxy_mangle_response(res):
    temp = res.serialize()
    file_temp = open('test.txt', 'a')
    file_temp.write(temp + '\n\n')
    file_temp.close()
```

However, the problem is, the response body is written as non human-readable gibberish even though it appears as HTML when inspected through something like Live HTTP headers (chrome extension).

The serialize() method is provided by proxpy and the implementation is this:

```
def serialize(self):
        # Response line
        s = "%s %s %s" % (self.proto, self.code, self.msg)
        s += HTTPMessage.EOL

        # Headers
        for n,v in self.headers.iteritems():
        for i in v:
        s += "%s: %s" % (n, i)
        s += HTTPMessage.EOL

        s += HTTPMessage.EOL

        # Body
        if not self.isChunked():
            s += self.body
        else:
            # FIXME: Make a single-chunk body
            s += "%x" % len(self.body) + HTTPMessage.EOL
            s += self.body + HTTPMessage.EOL
            s += HTTPMessage.EOL
            s += "0" + HTTPMessage.EOL + HTTPMessage.EOL

        return s
```

To reproduce this issue, hit 'dawn.com' after running proxpy. The first request which goes to dawn.com will reproduce the issue.

The following are the response headers:

```
CF-RAY  1b2c4934487f073d-AMS
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Tue, 03 Feb 2015 05:39:05 GMT
Server  cloudflare-nginx
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Vary    Accept-Encoding
X-Backend   www2
X-Developer Enjoy webdev? We like you, reach out at topcoder(at)compunode.com
```

I'm thinking this is some sort of encoding issue and there is some info in the headers which makes the browser interpret the response body correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the response body was compressed using `gzip`, as is apparent from the response header `Content-Encoding`. The browser decompresses it before displaying. Just need to decompress using `zlib` if the `Content-Encoding` header value is set to `gzip`.